# How to pass variables from one vm to another vm using bash script

Tags: bash, centos6, heredoc

What is the proper way to pass variable from one machine to another machine via bash script? In the below code I am trying to get the input from user and want to pass the same to remote machine, but the value is not getting accessed in remote machine, can anyone let me know the proper way to do it?

```
NEWLINE=$'\n'
read -s -p "Enter App FQDN:${NEWLINE}" APP_FQDN
read -s -p "Enter App Password:${NEWLINE}" APP_PASSWORD
read -s -p "Enter VD Password:${NEWLINE}" VD_PASSWORD
sshpass -p "$APP_PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T root@$APP_FQDN << 'EOSSH'
if true; then
 su - presto << 'PRESTO'
 source ~/.bash_profile
 cd /opt/vm/vchs/presto_agent
 pwd
 KEY=$( cat /opt/vm/vchs/presto_agent/config/settings.yml |grep '^key:'|sed 's/^key: //')
 echo $KEY
 echo $VD_PASSWORD
 PASSWORD=$(ruby /opt/vm/vchs/presto_agent/lib/obfuscation_util.rb encrypt $KEY $VD_PASSWORD)
 echo $PASSWORD
PRESTO
else
 echo "False"
fi
EOSSH
```

While executing the above script `$VD_PASSWORD` is echo blanks

Answer (score 1):

My original answer

```
ssh VD_PASSWORD="$VD_PASSWORD" ...
```

was wrong because it did not take into account the heredoc and it placed the setting of the environment variable in the wrong place. Even if you put the environment variable in the correct place

```
ssh ... user@remote VD_PASSWORD="$VD_PASSWORD" <<'EOSSH' ...
```

It does not work because of the heredoc.

I got this to work

```
VD_PASSWORD="$VD_PASSWORD"
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T user@remote <<EOSSH
echo $VD_PASSWORD
EOSSH
```

Note the lack of `'` around the EOSSH but that may not do what you want ( I really can't tell from the script).

It may be better to have your script on the remote host and then call it

```
ssh ... VD_PASSWORD="$VD_PASSWORD" /path/to/remote/script
```

Comment: sshpass -p "$APP_PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T root@$APP_FQDN VD_PASSWORD="$VD_PASSWORD"<< 'EOSSH'

This is not working, do I need to follow any specific format?

Answer (score 0):

To pass environment variables it may be needed to change the entries for `AcceptEnv` in [sshd_config(5)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sshd_config+5) and `SendEnv` in [ssh_config(5)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh_config+5).